# Why was the fire method removed from Laravel 5.5 Command class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Recently, there have been issues using other packages with L5.5. You get a Reflection Exception when you run commands on those packages because most packages use the fire() method and the L5.5 Illuminate command class requires just the handle() method. On previous versions, it could either be a fire or handle method. This will cause touching code that is not your own. Any wisdom behind this in L5.5? Will this be rectified soon? What effect would this have on existing packages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for the reasoning of the package creator. This question is best directed to the package maintainers.

Comment: They changed the name of the method from fire in Laravel 5 but removed the backwards compatibility in 5.5 from fire to handle.  It's a pretty simple fix to change the method name for any old packages...

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20024